# Can I save filter for columns at SQLDeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

It's annoying to preview all columns all the time (especially when tables has a lot of) and even worse to create filter after every restart of SQLDeveloper? 
I can't see there any option to save them.
Has someone workaround for this?
My version is 4.1.0.17.

Comment: I don't want to create additional views - it would rubbish schema/other views. This is good option but not so convenient as context action "columns" on "Data" tab. But your suggestion gave me some idea..

Answer (score 0):

1. List down the required columns in the select query. Compose the final query with only the columns you want in the select list. Save the query in your local as .sql file with a proper name of your choice. From next time open this file in SQL Worksheet. This would be applicable if you use the same query quite often.
2. Alternatively, you could create a new table from existing table, specify the columns in the order you want to display first and keep the rest columns towards the end.

Create table_new as select 
From table_old;

Drop table tqble_old;

Rename table_new to table_old;